# Ubuntu mysql file path location

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, terminal, command

I am newer in Ubuntu so I executed following query

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test INTO OUTFILE 'test.txt';
```

My question is where `test.txt` will store? I found in `/var/lib/mysql` but Not getting it.

When I execute same query then It will return

```
ERROR 1086 (HY000): File 'test.txt' already exists
```

Please Help me.

Comment: `whereis 'test.txt'` ????

Comment: Where it is stored? I mean path of `test.txt` file

Comment: put that command in terminal.It will show you the path

Comment: Which command I have to put in terminal?

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/whereis.1.html

Comment: That I am asking where is `test.txt` will store?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57191/discussion-between-samitha-and-sadikhasan).